# ¿Cómo restringir el acceso a 1 vez por día en PHP?

Tags: php

encontré este código en Github, es un script que genera cuentas/links de invitación.

Basta con presionar "Generate" para generar una cuenta, pero **necesito que solo se pueda acceder una vez al día a mi sitio para evitar abusos.**

¿Hay alguna forma de detectar si un usuario con una dirección IP ya accedió al sitio y no pueda generar otra cuenta?

**Código PHP:**

```
<?php

$minecraft_txt = file_get_contents("accounts/canva.txt");
$spotify_txt = file_get_contents("accounts/spotify.txt");

if(isset($_POST['generate'])){
    if(isset($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['type'])){
        $type = $_POST['type'];
        $type_arr = array("canva", "spotify");

        if(in_array($type, $type_arr)){
            if($type === "canva"){
                $mc_arr = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $minecraft_txt);
                $success = $mc_arr[array_rand($mc_arr)];
            }
            else if($type === "spotify"){
                $spot_arr = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $spotify_txt);
                $success = $spot_arr[array_rand($spot_arr)];
            }
        }
        else{
            $err = "Invalid account type";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Generator</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script>window.history.replaceState&&window.history.replaceState(null,null,window.location.href);</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <p class="title">GENERATOR NAME</p>
        <?php
        if(isset($err)){
            echo '<div class="alert error">'.$err.'</div>';
        }
        else if(isset($success)){
            echo '<div class="alert success">'.$success.'</div>';
        }
        ?>
        <form method="POST">
            <select name="type">
                <option value="minecraft">Canva</option>
                <option value="spotify">Spotify</option>
            </select>
            <button name="generate" type="submit">Generate</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Eso es todo lo que hace funcionar el script. No encuentro algo parecido ni en StackOverflow en inglés, agradecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Que tal si creas un campo en la DB llamado dia, y cuando un Usuario ingrese la primera vez le grabas en ese campo el Date, y si quiere ingresar nuevamente el mismo día se envias un mensaje diciendo que ya por ese dia no puede volver a ingresar.

Tambien puedes registrar su ultimo ingreso en la DB y cuando intente ingresar calculas la el tiempo que ha pasado con diff()

```
            $date1 = new DateTime($fechaUltimoIngreso);
            $date2 = new DateTime("now");
            $diff = $date1->diff($date2);
              $totalMinutos = ( (($diff->y) * 525600) + (($diff->m) * 43800) + (($diff->d) * 1440) + (($diff->h) * 60) + ($diff->i ) );
              if ( $totalMinutos > 1444) {
```

#### puede ingresar} else{

te faltan minutos para volver a ingresar
}

Comment: lo que pasa es que no sé como implementarlo :( soy bastante nuevo en esto y no sé como hacer lo que planteas @zenen

Comment: También sugiero que cuando alguien ingrese mediante javascript se haga el envió del un formulario a una bd donde capture los datos del dia del ingreso, la ip,  otro campo en la bd que se llene con una llave que sea algo como si no ha ingresado ponga 0 y si ya ingreso ponga 1, con eso cada vez que ingrese alguien le pides a php que haga una validación previa con la ip, el día y la llave, con eso si no supera la validación no le permita el ingreso de lo contrario si lo haga.

Comment: @CamiloKent pero no tengo idea de como :( solo sé HTML Y CSS bien